# Issue with installing a CocoaPods: Unable to find a specification

Tags: ios, git, github, cocoapods

I am trying to install this pod in my Xcode project: https://github.com/sw0906/SWCombox.git

There's no documentation about it whatsoever, I tried the following:

(1) pod 'SWCombox'

(2) pod 'SWCombox', :git => 'https://github.com/sw0906/SWCombox.git'

I am getting the following error all the time:

> [!] Unable to find a specification for `SWCombox`

Comment: it is not available in pods.

Comment: @Shubhank - So there is no way I can install it?

Comment: just install it manually by downloading the lib from github directly, then add it to your project and  check it in on your version control so you dont lose it

Comment: you can go ahead and include all relevant files inside your project. like checbox assets and classes. but it would require some more effort from your part. there is no good instruction for this lib. I would suggest using some other checkbox library

Comment: You can fork the library and add CocoaPods support yourself. Then you can suggest a pull-request to include your improvement into the upstream. That's how open source works!

Comment: Thanks all! Really appreciate it :D